# SSIS: Using a View for a Sql Server Package Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have set up a View as the source for a Sql Server Package Configuration that has the same name and columns as the default table.

It works in design-time but the package fails to load the configurations claiming the view is an Invalid Object at run-time. This seems like it should work because the view appears in the drop-down in the editor. Is there something I'm missing or is it impossible to use a View as the source of the package configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out. Just had to cast all of the columns to nvarchar(255).